# NoClassDefFoundError while integrating Yahoo in Application

Tags: java, android, yahoo

I'm developing an Application where I have integrated Yahoo so that I can retrive contacts from yahoo mail. I have imported the jar files in my App.

I'm getting following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime(416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-30 10:30:57.693:
E/AndroidRuntime(416): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` means that one class could not be found. In your case `CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer`.
Looks like you are using a third party library and have forgotten to add it( or add it correctly ) to the project build path.
Refer to this [link](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects) if it is the case.